# Using .pyd library in Jython

Tags: python, jython, cpython, pyd

Actually i'm about to start a project, in the company we are using java as a main technology in owr web app server (IBM WebSpher), but now we need to integrate existing technology with a new product recently purchased and is developed in C/CPython and ofer a SDK also in C and implementation in CPython (.pyd file), now i want to know if the kind of libraries are supported in jython actyally i'm working with Jython 2.7b1? or is there a way to use these kind of libraries?

Thanks and regards,
Serch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Jython FAQ](http://www.jython.org/archive/22/userfaq.html#is-jython-the-same-language-as-python)...

> Jython programs cannot use CPython extension modules written in C.
>   These modules usually have files with the extension .pyc, .pyd or
>   .dll. If you want to use such a module, you should look for an
>   equivalent written in pure Python or Java.

The only workaround would be to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to embed CPython in Java, although it would probably defeat the purpose of using Jython.

Comment: Since when is `.pyc` an extension module? I've only ever seen it used for cached bytecode (which it likely incompatible too, but it still seems out of place in that sentence).

Comment: @delnan Heh. Didn't notice that. I guess they figured it was easier to add that in there, rather than add a new FAQ entry specifically for CPython bytecode incompatibilities. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i will try to use directly the C libraries provided by the vendor, [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) has good look